# Python : Select element that contains particular data from a list of dict

Tags: python

I have a list of dict data and would like to get the `'id'` ,`'instrument'`and `'trade_id'` if the `'type'` is `'TAKE_PROFIT'`

```
b= [{'id': '9229',
  'instrument': 'USD_SGD',
  'price': '1.34505',
  'openTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:01.767987144Z',
  'initialUnits': '1000',
  'initialMarginRequired': '27.9310',
  'state': 'OPEN',
  'currentUnits': '1000',
  'realizedPL': '0.0000',
  'financing': '-0.3154',
  'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'unrealizedPL': '12.4128',
  'marginUsed': '28.5472',
  'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9240',
   'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:40:54.539350738Z',
   'replacesOrderID': '9230',
   'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT',
   'tradeID': '9229',
   'price': '1.50000',
   'timeInForce': 'GTC',
   'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT',
   'state': 'PENDING'},
  'stopLossOrder': {'id': '9231',
   'createTime': '2022-01-24T08:01:02.589631870Z',
   'type': 'STOP_LOSS',
   'tradeID': '9229',
   'price': '1.01000',
   'timeInForce': 'GTC',
   'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT',
   'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK',
   'state': 'PENDING'}},
 {'id': '9219',
  'instrument': 'USD_SGD',
  'price': '1.34465',
  'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:53.369040131Z',
  'initialUnits': '1000',
  'initialMarginRequired': '27.9312',
  'state': 'OPEN',
  'currentUnits': '1000',
  'realizedPL': '0.0000',
  'financing': '-0.3154',
  'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'unrealizedPL': '12.8314',
  'marginUsed': '28.5472'},
 {'id': '9216',
  'instrument': 'USD_SGD',
  'price': '1.34454',
  'openTime': '2022-01-24T07:45:41.086253690Z',
  'initialUnits': '1000',
  'initialMarginRequired': '27.9355',
  'state': 'OPEN',
  'currentUnits': '1000',
  'realizedPL': '0.0000',
  'financing': '-0.3154',
  'dividendAdjustment': '0.0000',
  'unrealizedPL': '12.9465',
  'marginUsed': '28.5472',
  'takeProfitOrder': {'id': '9246',
   'createTime': '2022-01-24T09:05:54.649091912Z',
   'replacesOrderID': '9217',
   'type': 'TAKE_PROFIT',
   'tradeID': '9216',
   'price': '1.50000',
   'timeInForce': 'GTC',
   'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT',
   'state': 'PENDING'}}]
```

I am trying with
`[d['id'] for d in b if d['type']=='TAKE_PROFIT']` but it return error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\oanda_p\forex_python-master\oanda_practice\oanda_api.py in <module>
----> 1 [d['id'] for d in b if d['type']=='TAKE_PROFIT']

d:\oanda_p\forex_python-master\oanda_practice\oanda_api.py in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [d['id'] for d in b if d['type']=='TAKE_PROFIT']

KeyError: 'type'
```

My desired output is a list of that contains `id`, `instrument` and `trade_id` if `type` is `TAKE_PROFIT`. The actual list is much longer, so it can contains a lot of data that `type` is `TAKE_PROFIT`

Comment: You need to access to key of nested dictionary using all keys chain - `d['takeProfitOrder']['type']`. Proper list comp: `[order["id"] for d in b if (order := d.get("takeProfitOrder")) and order["type"] == "TAKE_PROFIT"]`

Comment: ... and not all dicts have `'takeProfitOrder'` so `d.get('takeProfitOrder', {}).get('type')`

Comment: "I have a list of dict data" some of those dicts have nested dicts in them. Solving this problem is mainly a matter of *carefully looking at the data and understanding how it is structured*, rather than needing any special programming technique.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, it works to get alone `id`. However, It needs `instrument` and `trade_id` as well if 'type`  is 'TAKE_PROFIT`. Need to construct it in a list together instead of 3 lists

Comment: @bkcollection, if you really don't understand how to patch my list comprehension to retrieve 3 values you probably need to build your own script using techniques you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a little bit of insight of the database can writing a code that is much more simple.

In your example, it *seems* that "takeProfitOrder" will always be "TAKE_PROFIT". Also, "stopLossOrder" will always be "STOP_LOSS". Would you be able to **validate this assumption** based on documentation and your knowledge of how the data is generated?

Then, we can have some very simple python code:

```
mytrades = []
for element in b:
    try:
        e_id = element["id"]
        e_instrument = element["instrument"]
        e_tradeID = element["takeProfitOrder"]["tradeID"]   
        mytrades.append((e_id,e_instrument,e_tradeID))
    except:
        pass
```

And then, if you:

```
>>>>> print(mytrades)
[('9229', 'USD_SGD', '9229'), ('9216', 'USD_SGD', '9216')]
```

Two warnings:

- If there are "TAKE_PROFITS" of interest that are not "takeProfitOrder", then you could either add a second block with the necessary modifications, or create a small loop.
- If there are "takeProfitOrder" that are not of type "TAKE_PROFIT", then you should add one if statement just before the append.

Best regards,

Comment: Use `except KeyError:`. Quote from [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): *"When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare `except:` clause"*.